# Validating User Input using JavaFX and FXML

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Using JavaFX and FXML I want to validate users' input when they hit submit. 
looking at the .fxml doc, you'll see that I have 2 input fields one for zip code and one for cityname.  I am enforcing NumberTextField.java and CityNameTextField.java  from the xml file, but how can I make sure they are not blank when user hit submit?

FXMLDocument.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import validatetextfieldsfxml.custom.*?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="173.0" layoutY="89.0" text="ZipCode" />
      <Label layoutX="173.0" layoutY="118.0" text="CityName" />
      <NumberTextField fx:id="zipCodeTf" layoutX="257.0" layoutY="84.0" />
      <CityNameTextField fx:id="cityNameTf" layoutX="257.0" layoutY="113.0" />
      <Button fx:id="btn" layoutX="217.0" layoutY="162.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Submit" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

CityNameTextField.java

```
package validatetextfieldsfxml.custom;

import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
public class CityNameTextField extends TextField {

   public CityNameTextField(){
       this.setPromptText("Enter Your CityName");
   }

   @Override
   public void replaceText(int i, int il, String string){
       if(string.matches("[a-zA-Z]") || string.isEmpty()){
          super.replaceText(il, il, string);
       }
   }

    @Override
    public void replaceSelection(String string) {
        super.replaceSelection(string); 
    }



}
```

NumberTextField.java

```
package validatetextfieldsfxml.custom;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class NumberTextField extends TextField{
    public NumberTextField(){
        this.setPromptText("Enter Only numbers");
    }
    @Override
    public void replaceText(int i, int il, String string){
        if(string.matches("[0-9]") || string.isEmpty() ){
            super.replaceText(i, il, string);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void replaceSelection(String string){
        super.replaceSelection(string);
    }
}
```

Comment: In your controller you can check if them are empty. Doing string.isEmpty inside replaceText will not prevent the submit, it will just accept the new text only if the string is empty

Comment: @MarcoAcierno You need to allow an empty string in `replaceText` in order for the user to be able to delete characters.

Comment: You are not explicitly add a controller in your fxml with the fx:controller tag. Do you have added one elsewhere? I ask, because you set id-tags...

Comment: @NwDx There are actually use cases for `fx:id` even if there's no controller. (Though I can't really see how one would use a form like this without a controller.) See (updated) answer...

Comment: can you provide an example on how it can be done. I am not using a controller in my example as I was just testing.

Comment: @Moe thought it! So please follow James_D he will have a nice and good answer for you :-)

Answer (score 6):

In your controller's `initialize` method, just do

```
btn.disableProperty().bind(zipCodeTf.textProperty().isEmpty()
    .or(cityNameTf.textProperty().isEmpty()));
```

You can also do this directly in the FXML file with

```
  <Button fx:id="btn" text="Submit" 
       disable="${ cityNameTf.text.empty || zipCodeTf.text.empty }"/>
```

Comment: i havn't incoproated a controller as of yet, can you give me a complete example to use in my controller? right now I am loading the xml file Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

Comment: Just incorporate the controller and add the provided code in the initialize method. There's nothing more you need.

Comment: but how to alert the user to enter the required info?  instead of just disabling the button.

Comment: Any way you want. How is it normally done in UIs you use? Add a label saying the value is required, use `promptText` on the text fields, put an `*` next to the text fields, use a tooltip.... Just implement it the way that you think gives the best user experience.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for an example if you have one handy to model after. let me know if you do. Thanks again for your prompt answers!!

Comment: @Moe have you already checked the JavaFX Tutorial for TextField? [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/text-field.htm#BABBCEIG) you find it.

Comment: Moe there are a few existing libraries which provide validation implementation assistance, [ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/#decorationvalidation), [JideFX](http://www.jidesoft.com/jidefx/JideFX_Validation_Developer_Guide.pdf), [FXForm2](http://dooapp.github.io/FXForm2/), probably some others too.  You could either use one of those frameworks or write your own validators from scratch.  If it was just one or two text fields to validate, I'd just implement my own validation, if it is a large form based app, then investigate the libraries.